# Invalid conversion error in template class using CRTP

Tags: c++, static, polymorphism, crtp

I am fairly new to c++ and try to implement an [entity-component-system (ECS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity_component_system).

I have an inferface `IComponent` and a base-class called `Component` that implements the inferface. The base-class `Component` has many sub-classes (e.g `PositionComponent`, `VelocityComponent`, etc.).

I would like every sub-class of `Component` to have its own static list of instances of that class. For example `PositionComponent` should have a static list of all instances of `PositionComponent`.

Because I do not want to copy the same code in every sub-class I put the list in the base-class `Component`. But because it is static the sub-classes wouldn't get an own instance of it but instead use the list in the base-class.

While trying to solve this I stumbled upon the [curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to implement some form of static polymorphism.

My problem now is that when I call destroy on an object of type `PositionComponent` I get the following error in the last line of `Component::destroy` where I try to assign `this` to `pFirstInPool` :

```
invalid conversion from 'Component<PositionComponent>* const' to 'PositionComponent*'
```

Can this be fixed or is what I am trying to do simply not possible the way I designed it?

Here is the code:

**IComponent**

```
class IComponent
{
    public:
        virtual ~IComponent() {}
        virtual void destroy() = 0;
    protected:
        IComponent() {}
    private:
};
```

**Component**

```
template <typename T>
class Component : public IComponent
{
    public:
        virtual ~Component() {}

        inline Entity* getEntity() { return pEntity; }

        static T* create() {
            /* returns an object from the list of inactive objects (the pool) 
            or returns a new object if the pool is empty.
            then it adds it to the list of active objects */
            T* lpNew;
            if ( pFirstInPool == nullptr ) {
                lpNew = new T;
            }else{
                lpNew = pFirstInPool;
                if ( lpNew->getNext() != nullptr ) {
                    lpNew->getNext()->setPrev(nullptr);
                    pFirstInPool = lpNew->getNext();
                }else{
                    pFirstInPool = nullptr;
                }
            }
            if ( pFirst != nullptr ) {
                pFirst->setPrev(lpNew);
            }else{
                pLast = lpNew;
            }
            lpNew->setNext(pFirst);
            lpNew->setPrev(nullptr);
            pFirst = lpNew;
            return lpNew;
        }

        void destroy() {
            /* removes an object from the list of active objects
            and adds it to the list of inactive objects (the pool) */
            if ( this == pFirst ) {
                pFirst = pNext;
            }
            if ( this == pLast ) {
                pLast = pPrev;
            }
            if ( pPrev != nullptr ) {
                pPrev->setNext(pNext);
            }
            if ( pNext != nullptr ) {
                pNext->setPrev(pPrev);
            }
            pPrev = nullptr;
            pNext = pFirstInPool;
            pFirstInPool = this;
        }

        inline T* getPrev() { return pPrev; }
        inline T* getNext() { return pNext; }
        inline void setPrev( T* tpPrev ) { pPrev = tpPrev; }
        inline void setNext( T* tpNext ) { pNext = tpNext; }

        static inline T* getFirst() { return pFirst; }
        static inline T* getLast() { return pLast; }

    protected:
        Component() : lEnabled(true), pPrev(nullptr), pNext(nullptr) {}

    private:
        Entity* pEntity;
        bool lEnabled;
        T* pPrev;
        T* pNext;
        static T* pFirst;
        static T* pLast;
        static T* pFirstInPool;

};

template <typename T>
T* Component<T>::pFirst = nullptr;
template <typename T>
T* Component<T>::pLast = nullptr;
template <typename T>
T* Component<T>::pFirstInPool = nullptr;
```

**PositionComponent**

```
class PositionComponent : public Component<PositionComponent>
{
    public:
        PositionComponent();
        /*...*/
    protected:
    private:
};
```

**VelocityComponent**

```
class VelocityComponent : public Component<VelocityComponent>
{
    public:
        VelocityComponent();
        /*...*/
    protected:
    private:
};
```

Comment: `this` has the type `Component<Something>*`. You have some some pointer of type `Something*` and try to assign `this` of type `Component<Something>*`  (no respect to cv-qualifiers here) to it. That's not possible. It's like assigning class `A` to class `B`, but `B` has no rule to convert an `A` to a `B`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't really understand why `this` gets the type `Component<Something>*`. From my understanding it should be `Something*`, because it says `new T` and `T` is `Something`

Comment: But thats `lpNew`! `lpNew` is the thing, which points to the memory you create with `new T`. `this` is a pointer to the instance itself where it gets used. You use it inside the `destroy` function of `Component<Something>`, thus...

Comment: Ah, I see. I replaced all occurences of `T*` with `Component<T>*` now and it compiles. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Well it should work, too. But its good that I were able to help you ;)